# Wordpress - Create a page when creating a user

Tags: wordpress

I would like to create a function that creates a page in wordpress that uses a specific page title, specific URL, and is under an already exisiting parent page, when ever a new user is created.

An example:

Creating a new user call `user1`, will also create a new page called `User1's Page` with a slug of `user1s-page` under a specified parent page ID.

Comment: try this here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: by the function   $user_id = wp_create_user() you get the  created user id and after that  you can add post for this user  by   wp_insert_post( $user_id)   it  will add the post  you can pass the parameter like page name and  status publish and unpublished  fo this  for more detail check these funtion in wp codex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test this while writing but it should do the trick. Make sure you set $post_parent to the ID of the page you want to use as the parent. It's currently set to 0 so no parent.

```
function wpse_user_registration_create_page( $user_id ) {
    // Get the new user by their ID.
    $new_user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );

    // Check a user was found.
    if ( ! $new_user )
        return;

    // Create the post title. E.g. User1's Page
    $post_title = ucfirst( $new_user->display_name ) . "'s Page";

    // SET THE ID OF THE PARENT PAGE HERE!!!
    $post_parent = 0;

    $post_args = array(
        "post_name"   => sanitize_title( $post_title ),
        "post_title"  => $post_title,
        "post_type"   => "page",
        "post_status" => "publish",
        "post_author" => $new_user->ID,
        "post_parent" => $post_parent,
    );

    wp_insert_post( $post_args );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse_user_registration_create_page' );
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, this works perfectly for what I wanted!

Comment: Pleased I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to hook into the register user hook, here;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

Then build a function which inserts a post (page) using this;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post